# Destination folder for bcc32c compiler

Tags: c++builder

How to change the destination folder for `.exe` files generated by bcc32c compiler?

For example, the following command:

> "bcc32c C:\Users\mvolodin\Documents\BCC32\Hello_World.c"

emits the `.exe` file in:

> C:\Users\mvolodin

not in the folder containing the `.c` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable file was emitted in the working directory of the Command Prompt which, in my case, was the user folder:

> C:\Users\mvolodin